# where are all the Latin subscript letters?

Tags: unicode, subscript, xmlconvert

I've been struggling to find some subscript letters, especially "b"
I've already looked up the Wikipedia:
[image: what is Wikipedia offering]

I've tried to copy their unicode, xml codes and paste to some convertor websites but it did not work.

Are there a way to get the subscript of these letters that does not found in the wikipedia etc

Comment: ^^ in which one of the answers links and quotes the Unicode FAQ question *"[Why doesn't Unicode have a full set of superscripts and subscripts?](https://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html#Pf8)"*.